# Difference in CPU Wattage Question

Tags: cpu-cache, cpu-pipelines

If I have 2 CPU's of the same manufacturer... say AMD

Both are Quad-Core, Both are rated at 3.6Ghz

1 is 100W, the other is 65W

Will the one with the higher wattage out-perform the lower one and why?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an analogy from the world of light bulbs. An incandescent light bulb operates at 15LPW (Lumens per Watt), while a LED light bulb operates at 45LPW. Suppose for the moment that both give the same spectrum of light (which is wrong). Suppose we feed the incandescent light bulb 9 Watts and the LED light bulb 3 Watts. Both will produce 105 Lumens, but the LED light will be more efficient.

The example with the CPUs is the same. Different technologies result in different power efficiency, but otherwise they could have the same *effectiveness*, e.g. as measured by FLOPS. The only way to answer your question is to check the specs of the CPUs — CPU frequency is only part of the picture.

Comment: There might be *some* difference. The 100W bin is less constrained (more potential variability among cores) and likely has higher leakage transistors (implying faster switching and greater influence of heat dissipation), so when a single core is active the 100W (with its full 100W thermal budget) *might* clock slightly higher than a single core in the 65W chip (with its 65W thermal budget). Not being an EE, I am not certain about this.